# Image flickering while geometryReader swipes

Tags: swiftui, navigation, swiftui-navigationlink, geometryreader

The picture flickers when swiping when I use NavigationLink. (Section One)
I solved the image flickers problem. I used a different NavigationLink function. (Section Two)
the problems don't stop there. When the navigation is running, the image shifts to the left while switching to the next page. (Section 3)

video link [here](https://youtu.be/63gIazlbjv0)

**MovieCell**

```
struct MovieCell: View {
    var width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    var height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    var movie: Movie
    @Binding var isOpeningDetailView: Bool
    var body: some View {
        
            GeometryReader { geometryReader in
                    
                    Image(movie.poster)
                        .resizable()
                        
                        .frame(width: width, height: height * 0.75)
                        .offset(x: -geometryReader.frame(in: .global).minX)
                        
                }
            
                .frame(height: height * 0.75)
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .padding(10)
                .background(Blur())
                .cornerRadius(15)
            
//                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        
          
    }
}
```

**MainView**

***Section One***

```
NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Image(selected.poster)
                    .resizable()
                    .overlay(Blur().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                VStack {
                    TabView(selection: $selected) {
                        ForEach(movieList, id: \.self) { item in
                            
                            NavigationLink(
                                destination: DetailView(),
                                label: {
                                    MovieCell(movie: item, isOpeningDetailView: $isOpeneningDetailView)
                                })
                            
                        }
                    }
                    .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
                    .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
                    
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            
        }
```

***Section Two***

```
TabView(selection: $selected) {
                        ForEach(movieList, id: \.self) { item in
                            ZStack {
                                MovieCell(movie: item, isOpeningDetailView: $isOpeneningDetailView)
                                NavigationLink("", destination: DetailView(), isActive: $isOpeneningDetailView)
                            }
                            .onTapGesture {
                                withAnimation {
                                    self.isOpeneningDetailView = true
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
```

***Section Three***

**Normal**

image link [here](https://ibb.co/72yjPxD)

**When I Swipe**

image link [here](https://ibb.co/9N564wP)

the problem is here.

While navigating - the value is changing rapidly. When I remove the minus sign, the picture fits in its original place

**In GeometryReader**

```
.offset(x: (-)geometryReader.frame(in: .global).minX)//I deleted - negative sign
```

This is what I see instantly while navigating
[image]